# Script to log off users from a terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2003

I would like to log off all users from my terminal server (running Windows Server 2003) at 7 PM every night. What script might I use that will accomplish this?
Thanks, in advance, for your help!

Comment: This might help, it explains how to do part of what you are after: http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/server-2003-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will close all RDP (Remote Desktop) connections:

```
rwinsta rdp-tcp
```

Comment: Can this command be added to a batch file and run on schedule?  Is there any concern about running this command unattended (i.e. on a schedule at night)?  Thanks!